# Getting to know about Captive Portal

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, captivenetwork, captiveportal

We have created a Captive Portal which opens up whenever you connect to a Wi-Fi network. Initially, the page displayed on the Captive Portal was rendered on the server side.

Now we are adding some AJAX functionality on the page which is triggered by some user action. However, we are seeing very non-deterministic and random behavior. Sometimes the AJAX calls are successful and sometimes it is not even hitting the network (checked via **WireShark**).

Key facts about the AJAX call --

1. The ajax calls are being made to a different domain than the page. The server does allow CORS headers and the same is working fine from a normal browser, however, failing in the Captive Portal.
2. The ajax calls are asynchronous in nature (although tried synchronous calls as well - no luck).
3. I am setting few headers in the ajax call (authorization, client-id, user-id).
4. Both GET and POST are facing the issue.
5. The status code of the failed call is 0.
6. The issue is mostly with Apple devices. In Mac it fails every time, in iPhones it's random. The strange part is - the same iPhone behaves differently at different times.

There is no much resource out there to find out the technical specifications about the Captive Portal. The few that is available are not helping or have become obsolete (as I tested out that cookies are working and somewhere I read it's not available in the captive network).

One key thing to consider here is - if the AJAX call is made to the same domain it's always successful. But if same domain policy is the thing, the randomization of the behavior cannot be explained. I checked for some info in the WebKit code as well (https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/b46afedc13edea0847ebf02414f803bbe9781b70/Source/WebCore/xml/XMLHttpRequest.cpp#L567) but did not have much luck there too.

The below is like one browser information where it's failing --
*Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.3.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15B150*

The below is the Javascript code for the ajax call --

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // do something good
    } else {
        // do something evil
    }
};
// Call is made to some IP different than the domain
xhttp.open("GET", "http://255.255.255.255:255/xyz", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('authorization', 'some-random-hex-digit');
xhttp.setRequestHeader('client-id', 'some-random-client-id');
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({}));
```

> Anyone have faced similar issues or may bring up some light here? I am
>   stuck like for 2 days.